# DOS batch: force echo of single statement?

Tags: syntax, echo, batch-file

In my DOS batch file, I use the "@" symbol to suppress the echo of that statement before execution when echo is ON.

How should I force the echo of a statement when echo is OFF (I'm hoping for another single character, but all answers welcome)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that there is no way to do it. You can wrap commands you need to be echoed between `echo on` and `@echo off` but this is ugly, I think. Another option is to keep `echo on` and use `@` for every command you don't want to echo and keeping echo-ables without `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not as powerful solution as @ : surround the commands you want to echo by "echo on" then "echo off".

```
@echo on
your commands
@echo off
```